# iPad mapping application with custom maps

Tags: geotiff-tiff, software-recommendations, ipad

I'd like to load custom maps onto my iPad and use them offline with the GPS for navigation. These are maps I can prepare in any format and projection.

Is there an application that can take, for example, a GeoTIFF or group of GeoTIFFs and use them as the background with a GPS dot overlay?

**Use case**: I'm navigating about 100 km by snow-mobile across part of Antarctica. Normally we use standard GPS, but those screens are tiny, hard to see through goggles and hoods, and hard to interact with through gloves. I'd like to use an iPad (and a stylus to get around the gloved issue) because it has a nice big screen. I'll pack it with hand-warmers to keep it functional.

**Data set**: I have 0.5 m/pixel images of the terrain. At that resolution we can see the (visible) crevasses and the sensors (GPS, seismic) that we are trying to find, although they have moved a few 10s to 100s of m with the ice as it flows. Each image covers about 17 square km and is about 4 GB in size. I can generate these images as more smaller files, move up to 1 m/pixel if necessary, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had pretty good experiences playing around with iGIS:
http://www.geometryit.com/igis/

> iGIS represents a new era in mobile GIS solutions by 
>   enabling users to load, view, investigate, create and export their own
>   spatial data over a background of Google Maps imagery.

It was relatively easy to work with and seemed stable - granted I didn't use it extensively but the ~10 hours I did use it it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

I've been impressed with [Tiled Maps](https://itunes.apple.com/nz/app/tiled-maps/id472255447?mt=8).

Easy to use - and you can create your own maps to use offline with 3rd party app - [Map Tiler](http://www.maptiler.org).