# How to rendering and manipulate GeoTIFF image in iOS devices?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, ios, arcgis-ios

I am experienced iOS developer but I am new to geographical information manipulation. I am developing an iOS application that require me to render a geotiff image file (as a map) and be able to edit the map by placing different objects. And export it as a XML file. Can anyone please recommend me some libraries that can help me with it.

[iPad mapping application with custom maps](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43315/ipad-mapping-application-with-custom-maps)

The answers in this question talk about different application that does that. But I am building an app, so I need libraries/SDK that enable this.

Is ArcGIS a good choice?

Comment: Have not done anything on iOS but you should check the [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for iOS](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/).

Comment: Thank you @MarceloVilla , Does ArcGIS helps in this for other platform you might have worked on?

Comment: Maybe something like ArcGIS Web AppBuilder or the ArcGIS API for JavaScript if you want to create a web app rather than an iOS app. However you might need acces to a server to do the exporting to XML step. There are also other Open Source libraries that let the user interact and create data with a map on an interface.

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a native iOS app using GDAL to manage the vector data, and OpenLayers (in a UIWebView) to display the layers (both raster and vector).

For vector layers, the app uses GeoJSON to communicate between OpenLayers and GDAL.  It can use WMTS/TMS/WMS for raster layers.

There is a bit of a learning curve for both GDAL and for OpenLayers.  But the app works very well.

For GeoTIFF you can either:

- Use MapTiler (or similar) to convert to TMS before importing the image to the app (OpenLayers can read TMS locally)
- Set up a server (eg Geoserver) with the GeoTIFF as a layer that can feed out the data to your app as either WMTS, TMS, or WMS across the network